# Safest and most reliable way to measure short intervals in Python? (cross-platform, cross-hardware, resistant to DST and leap seconds)

Tags: python, datetime, time, dst, leap-second

### The more I read about datetime arithmetic, the bigger a headache I get.

There's lots of different kinds of time:

- Civil time
- UTC
- TAI
- UNIX time
- system time
- thread time
- CPU time

And then the clocks can run faster or slower or jump backwards or forwards because of

- daylight savings
- moving across timezones
- leap seconds
- NTP synchronization
- general relativity

And how these are dealt with depends in turn on:

- Operating system
- Hardware
- Programming language

So please can somebody tell me, for my specific use case, the **safest and most reliable** way to measure a short interval? Here is what I am doing:

I'm making a **game** in **Python** (3.7.x) and I need to keep track of how long it has been since certain events. For example, how long the player has been holding a button, or how long since an enemy has spotted the player, or how long since a level was loaded. Timescales should be **accurate to the millisecond** (nanoseconds are overkill).

### Here are scenarios I want to be sure are averted:

- You play the game late at night. In your timezone, on that night, the clocks go forward an hour at 2am for DST, so the minutes go: 1:58, 1:59, 2:00, 3:01, 3:02. Every time-related variable in the game suddenly has an extra hour added to it -- it thinks you'd been holding down that button for an hour and 2 seconds instead of just 2 seconds. Catastrophe ensues.
- The same, but the IERS decides to insert or subtract a leap second sometime that day. You play through the transition, and all time variables get an extra second added or subtracted. Catastrophe ensues.
- You play the game on a train or plane and catastrophe ensues when you cross a timezone boundary and/or the International Date Line.
- The game works correctly in the above scenarios on some hardware and operating systems, but not others. I.e. it breaks on Linux but not Window, or vice versa.

And I can't really write tests for these since the problematic events come around so rarely. I need to get it right the first time. So, what time-related function do I need to use? I know there's plain old `time.time()`, but also a bewildering array of other options like

- `time.clock()`
- `time.perf_counter()`
- `time.process_time()`
- `time.monotonic()`
- and then nanosecond variants of all of the above.

From reading the documentation it **seems** like `time.monotonic()` is the one I want. But if reading about all the details of timekeeping has taught me anything, it's that these things are never quite what they seem. Once upon a time, I thought I knew what a "second" was. Now I'm not so sure.

So, how do I make sure my game clocks work properly?

Comment: Sorry, but what is the problem to bind everything to UTC timestamp? From all your list of possible issues it covers all (except probably IERS corrections, I'm not sure).

Comment: You mean `time.time()`? Documentation says the handling of leap-seconds is platform-dependent, and

"Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls."

So that sounds a bit worrying.

Comment: I mean `int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp() * 1000)` which will return unix timestamp in miliseconds. And add simple `while new_time < old_time` to prevent issue you describe.

Comment: Leap seconds can go forwards and backwards though.

Comment: One second really matters in your game? Normally such as stuff calculated on server side.

Comment: Yes, a second does matter, it's a fast-paced game. Especially if an error might result in negative-second intervals or something silly like that. Also no server-side, it is single player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification of time module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) is the best place to look for details about each of those.

There, you can easily see that:

- `time.clock()` is deprecated and should be replaced with other functions
- `time.process_time()` counts only CPU time spent by your process, so it is not suitable for measuring wall clock time (which is what you need)
- `time.perf_counter()` has the same problem as `time.process_time()`
- `time.time()` is just about right, but it will give bad timings if user modifies the current time
- `time.monotonic()` - this seems to be the safest bet for measuring time intervals - note that this does not give you current time at all, but it gives you a correct difference between two time points

As for the nanoseconds versions, you should use those only if you need nanoseconds.